# Subscript out of range 9

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with this code:

```
With wb2
    .SaveAs Filename:=wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx"
End With
wb2.Activate
Set wb3 = Workbooks(wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx") 
wb2.Close
wb3.Activate
```

When it reaches this line `Set wb3 = Workbooks(wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx")`, it says:

> Subscript out of range

I'm trying to get the path of the currently opened workbook. I've tried many ways but is not working. Any help?

Comment: please remember to select an answer which you found most appropriate to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the path of the current workbook just try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
'or
ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

or in your case

```
wb2.Path & "\" & wb2.Name
'or
wb2.FullName
```

Comment: it's saying now object required.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do in the line Set wb3 = Workbooks(wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx") ? Creating a copy of the workbook?

Comment: I've already copied the workbook. Then next is I have to activate the copied workbook so that I can do some editing. That's why I'm creating a new variable and assign it to the copied wb. Or do you have any better way than mine? thanks!

Comment: If you copy the workbook under a new name you already have a copy. So you just can continue with your current workbook wb2. You do not need to use wb3.

Comment: Thanks! That's the scenario that I haven't seen.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb2
        .SaveAs Filename:=wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    End With
    wb2.Activate
    Set wb3 = Workbooks(wb2.Path & "\sample2.xlsx")
    wb2.Close
    wb3.Activate
End Sub
```